# Parallelize brute force generation

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I've searched a lot for this, but was unable to find something I could grasp my head around. What I'm searching for is how to make this algorithm parallel. It doesn't matter the way its parallel, such as multithreaded or multiprocessing or even distributed computing, but how exactly would I split up the work between nodes or cores?

```
def bruteforce(charset, maxlength):
    return (''.join(candidate)
        for candidate in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(charset, repeat=i)
        for i in range(1, maxlength + 1)))
```

Comment: start by splitting in several instructions.

Comment: Is the order in which results are produced important? What range of values do you have in mind for `len(charset)` and `maxlength`? Do you want it to run *faster* after parallelizing or is this just curiosity? (That's not a snarky question - for example, CPU-bound tasks run *slower* using threads under CPython.)

Comment: The order of results produced is not important no. The range can vary. Yes the reason for parallelizing would be to somewhat speed it up. If you have a suggestion on how to calculate this with gpu I wouldn't mind it :) Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "gpu" means.  The code I gave in my answer should give you nearly a speedup of a factor of `N` if you have `N` cores to devote to this.  That's because very little inter-process communication is required - as written, a brief description of work is passed to a worker process, and then the latter generates about a million strings all on its own.  You can make it do even more work per invocation by increasing `strings_per_chunk`.

Comment: GPU, or graphical processing unit. As in using PyCUDA or something. But thank you anyway. This helps me tons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have to do is get disenchanted with 1-liner disease ;-)  That is, parallel processing adds many complexities of its own, so you want to keep your code as simple and transparent as possible.  Here's a way that generalizes @BasSwinckels's suggestion.  It's not short!  But it's very effective:  it will nail your CPU meter to the wall no matter how many cores you have.

```
CHARSET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx"
MAX_LENGTH = 6  # generate all strings from CHARSET with length 1 thru MAX_LENGTH
NUM_PROCESSES = None # defaults to all available cores

from itertools import product

# string_gen is what the workers run.  Everything else
# runs in the main program.
def string_gen(prefix, suffix_len, length):
    # Generate all strings of length `length` starting with `prefix`.
    # If length > suffix_len, only the last suffix_len characters
    # need to be generated.
    num_done = 0
    if length <= suffix_len:
        assert prefix == ""
        for t in product(CHARSET, repeat=length):
            result = "".join(t)
            # do something with result
            num_done += 1
    else:
        assert len(prefix) + suffix_len == length
        for t in product(CHARSET, repeat=suffix_len):
            result = prefix + "".join(t)
            # do something with result
            num_done += 1
    return num_done

def record_done(num):
    global num_done
    num_done += num
    print num_done, "done so far"

def do_work(pool, strings_per_chunk=1000000):
    # What's the most chars we can cycle through without
    # exceeding strings_per_chunk?  Could do with this
    # logs, but I'm over-reacting to 1-liner disease ;-)
    N = len(CHARSET)
    suffix_len = 1
    while N**suffix_len <= strings_per_chunk:
        suffix_len += 1
    suffix_len -= 1
    print "workers will cycle through the last", suffix_len, "chars"

    # There's no point to splitting up very short strings.
    max_short_len = min(suffix_len, MAX_LENGTH)
    for length in range(1, max_short_len + 1):
        pool.apply_async(string_gen, args=("", suffix_len, length),
                         callback=record_done)
    # And now the longer strings.
    for length in range(max_short_len + 1, MAX_LENGTH + 1):
        for t in product(CHARSET, repeat=length-suffix_len):
            prefix = "".join(t)
            pool.apply_async(string_gen, args=(prefix, suffix_len, length),
                             callback=record_done)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES)
    num_done = 0
    do_work(pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    expected = sum(len(CHARSET)**i
                   for i in range(1, MAX_LENGTH + 1))
    assert num_done == expected, (num_done, expected)
```

There are multiple pieces to this because what you want is "lumpy":  strings of a variety of sizes.  Parallel gimmicks are usually easier the more utterly uniform the structure of the problem.  But lumpiness can be handled - it just takes more code.

Do note the `assert` statements, and the "useless" computations of `num_done`.  Parallel code adds brand new dimensions of complexity, so do yourself a favor and code defensively from the start.  You're going to try many things that simply won't work - that happens to everyone.

Note too that breaking free of 1-liner disease also gives a more efficient approach, even without multiple cores:  computing and joining the `prefix` just once for the longer strings will save countless billions of redundant joins over the course of longer runs.

Have fun :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with all of this. This helps so much. I am going to take a little time to actually understand this, but it makes things so much easier to learn. Thanks for helping. 

Edit: I also apologize for having one-line disease ;) I like writing quick code sometimes.

Comment: could you take a look at my other question concerning the script you wrote? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198348/python-parallel-hash-bruteforce

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your generator expression correctly, you are trying to generate all the words with a length from 1 .. `maxlength` given a certain alphabet.

I don't know exactly how you want to split your problem (do you have `N` workers?), but one obvious way would be to split the list of words just by the first letter, hand those out to the various parallel workers, which then all have to append all possible combinations of words with 0 .. `maxlength - 1` letters from the alphabet.

Comment: This isn't something I have thought of before, but it seems like it could work. I essentially just assumed to split the charset by how many workers I had. Example: [["a, "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]], but this wouldn't allow workers to generate strings such as: "adc". So thank you for clarifying.

Comment: They would still be able to generate that combination. You only split up the possible chars for the first letter, the rest of the word should still be chosen from the complete alphabet. You only have to change the function signature into `do_work(first_letters, alphabet)`.

Comment: Would the first letters all be different for each worker, or would it be incremented through the alphabet?

Comment: As you want. Think of it as having a telephone book with names with different length, that are sorted A-Z. Now rip the telephone book apart in as many pieces as you want.