# Python Parallel hash bruteforce

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have this script modified from a different script written by another user on this site. I'm trying to understand it the best I can, but am having difficulty. When I attempt to crack a hash using the charset as maybe only lowercase letters, it works just fine. But when I try cracking hash that has numbers and letters in it, it won't work unless I increase the "spc" variable from 1000000 to 100000000.

```
import itertools
import math
import string
import multiprocessing
import hashlib
import traceback
import sys

def hashstring(string, algorithm):
    return hashlib.new(algorithm, string).hexdigest()

def gen_product(prefix, charset, length):
    for string in itertools.product(charset, repeat=length):
        yield prefix + "".join(string)

def string_generator(prefix, hash, suffix_length, length, charset, hashalg):
    num_done = 0
    if length <= suffix_length:
        assert prefix == ""
        for possible in gen_product("", charset, length):
            if hashstring(possible, hashalg) == hash:
                return possible
    else:
        assert len(prefix) + suffix_length == length
        for possible in gen_product(prefix, charset, suffix_length):
            if hashstring(possible, hashalg) == hash:
                return possible

    return None

def run_string_generator(*args):
    try:
        return string_generator(*args)
    except:
        raise Exception("".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))

def do_work(pool, hash, charset, length, hashalg, spc=100000000):
    n = len(charset)
    suffix_len = int(math.ceil(math.log(spc) / math.log(n)) - 1)

    max_short_len = min(suffix_len, length)
    for length in range(1, max_short_len + 1):
        result = pool.apply_async(run_string_generator, args = ("", hash, suffix_len, length, charset, hashalg))
        if result.get() != None:
            return result.get()
    for length in range(max_short_len + 1, length + 1):
        for prefix in gen_product("", charset, length - suffix_len):
            result = pool.apply_async(run_string_generator, args = (prefix, hash, suffix_len, length, charset, hashalg))    
            if result.get() != None:
                return result.get()

    return None


def parallel_bruteforce(hash, charset, length, hashalg="md5", spc=1000000, cores=None):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
    result = do_work(pool, hash, charset, length, hashalg, spc)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Starting..."
    #The hash is an md5 encryption of "test1"
    print parallel_bruteforce("5a105e8b9d40e1329780d62ea2265d8a", string.ascii_lowercase +  string.digits, 5, spc=100000000)
```

Edit:
The link to the other post with the original code is https://stackoverflow.com/a/20135250/1769995

Comment: Python is definitely not the best language for this.

Comment: @Blender This is just a learning exercise and python is the language I understand the best. I don't care about speed.

Comment: What *exactly* does "it won't work" mean? I'm not in the mood for blind guessing ;-)

Comment: What it seems like is it's only searching a portion of the keyspace and not all of it.

Comment: @Blender, so what is the best language for this? ;-) It's easy enough to apply all available cores in parallel using Python, and the expensive bits (like computing MD5 digests) are implemented in C. In Python3 I'd use a mutable bytearray and generate "the strings" via simple arithmetic, but that's about it for opportunities for large speedups.  More fruitful than switching languages would be switching to custom hardware, like the Big Boys do ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters: Well, the "best" language really depends on the hardware at your disposal. TimCPogue *was* writing the expensive bits in Python, which is what I was referring to. I should've made "this" a little more specific.

Comment: @Blender, but CPython's md5 digest computation *is* implemented in C, borrowed from LibTomCrypt.  The Python code is just generating strings to feed to it.  Sure, that can be done faster - even in Python ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry in advance that I don't have time now to explain this.  It's an edit of my earlier answer that retains the parallelism and stops all the workers "early" if the hash is cracked.  In general, you do not want to pass arguments that never vary across invocations, so I do much more here at module level than you do.  The attached code displays:

```
workers will cycle through the last 3 chars
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
[etc]
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
the plaintext is 'test1'
```

Here it is.  Note that it plays another low-level efficiency trick, by materializing `PAIRS`, a list of all 2-character strings from the alphabet.  That again saves countless billions of redundant joins over the course of a long run.

```
import string
import hashlib
from itertools import product

CHARSET = string.ascii_lowercase +  string.digits
MAX_LENGTH = 5
NUM_PROCESSES = None # defaults to all available cores

HASHALG = "md5"
HASH = "5a105e8b9d40e1329780d62ea2265d8a"

PAIRS = ["".join(t) for t in product(CHARSET, repeat=2)]

def make_bases(count):
    bases = [PAIRS] * (count // 2)
    if count & 1:
        bases.insert(0, CHARSET)
    return bases

# string_gen is what the workers run.  Everything else
# runs in the main program.
def string_gen(prefix, suffix_len, length):
    # Generate all strings of length `length` starting with `prefix`.
    # If length > suffix_len, only the last suffix_len characters
    # need to be generated.
    if length <= suffix_len:
        assert prefix == ""
        bases = make_bases(length)
    else:
        assert len(prefix) + suffix_len == length
        bases = make_bases(suffix_len)
    for t in product(*bases):
        result = prefix + "".join(t)
        # do something with result
        if hashlib.new(HASHALG, result).hexdigest() == HASH:
            return result

def record_done(result):
    global all_done, the_secret
    print ".",
    if result is not None:
        print
        the_secret = result
        all_done = True
        pool.close()
        pool.terminate() # stop all workers! we're done

def do_work(pool, strings_per_chunk=1000000):
    global all_done, the_secret
    all_done = False
    the_secret = None
    # What's the most chars we can cycle through without
    # exceeding strings_per_chunk?
    N = len(CHARSET)
    suffix_len = 1
    while N**suffix_len <= strings_per_chunk:
        suffix_len += 1
    suffix_len -= 1
    print "workers will cycle through the last", suffix_len, "chars"

    # There's no point to splitting up very short strings.
    max_short_len = min(suffix_len, MAX_LENGTH)
    for length in range(1, max_short_len + 1):
        pool.apply_async(string_gen, args=("", suffix_len, length),
                         callback=record_done)
        if all_done:
            return
    # And now the longer strings.
    for length in range(max_short_len + 1, MAX_LENGTH + 1):
        for t in product(*make_bases(length - suffix_len)):
            prefix = "".join(t)
            pool.apply_async(string_gen, args=(prefix, suffix_len, length),
                             callback=record_done)
            if all_done:
                return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES)
    do_work(pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    if the_secret is None:
        print "didn't crack it!"
    else:
        print "the plaintext is", repr(the_secret)
```

**CAUTION:** As written, that code is "too parallel" for larger problem sizes and/or very small `strings_per_chunk`.  The main program can fire off `apply_async()` calls far faster than the worker processes can deal with them, so the `multiprocessing` machinery can end up trying to queue billions of work items.  Then you can run out of RAM, or other system resources.  Of course that's fixable too ;-)

### Fixing that

`multiprocessing` doesn't expose any ways to throttle its internal queues, so "a natural" solution is to add a layer with our own queue.  This keeps up to 3 pending tasks per processor in `multiprocessing`'s internal task queue, but blocks the main program from generating more prefixes so long as its own queue gets longer than that.  Also fiddled the logic to raise an `EarlyExit` exception when the hash has been cracked; this is easier and cleaner than mucking with global flags.  What follows is meant to replace everything above from `record_done()` down:

```
class EarlyExit(Exception):
    def __init__(self, result):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.result = result

class CustomDispatcher:
    def __init__(self, pool):
        from collections import deque
        self.pool = pool
        self.q = deque()

    def queue_work(self, *args):
        while len(self.q) > NUM_PROCESSES * 3:
            # provided the workers have significant work to do,
            # it will "take a long time" to finish the work
            # already queued.  Rather than swamp the mp machinery
            # with even more pending tasks, wait for some to
            # finish first.
            self.unqueue()
        self.q.append(self.pool.apply_async(string_gen, args))

    def unqueue(self):
        if self.q:
            # note:  the main program spends most of its time
            # blocked on the .get(); that's because it can
            # generate prefixes far faster than workers can
            # process them
            result = self.q.popleft().get()
            print ".",
            if result is not None:
                print
                raise EarlyExit(result)

    def drain(self):
        while self.q:
            self.unqueue()

def do_work(dispatch, strings_per_chunk=10000000):
    # What's the most chars we can cycle through without
    # exceeding strings_per_chunk?
    N = len(CHARSET)
    suffix_len = 1
    while N**suffix_len <= strings_per_chunk:
        suffix_len += 1
    suffix_len -= 1
    print "workers will cycle through the last", suffix_len, "chars"
    print "so each dot represents", \
          format(len(CHARSET)**suffix_len, ","), "strings"

    # There's no point to splitting up very short strings.
    max_short_len = min(suffix_len, MAX_LENGTH)
    for length in range(1, max_short_len + 1):
        dispatch.queue_work("", suffix_len, length)
    # And now the longer strings.
    for length in range(max_short_len + 1, MAX_LENGTH + 1):
        for t in product(*make_bases(length - suffix_len)):
            dispatch.queue_work("".join(t), suffix_len, length)
    dispatch.drain()  # check remaining tasks for a winner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES)
    dispatch = CustomDispatcher(pool)
    try:
        do_work(dispatch)
    except EarlyExit as e:
        print "the plaintext is", repr(e.result)
    else:
        print "didn't crack it!"
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate() # stop all workers! we're done
    pool.join()
```

The combinatorial explosion of possibilities as the size of the alphabet and/or size of the longest string generated increase may mean you'll wait forever for a result, but at least with this change you won't run out of RAM - and you'll utilize all your cores at close to 100% capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

```
    result = pool.apply_async(run_string_generator, args = (prefix, hash, suffix_len, length, charset, hashalg))    
    if result.get() != None:
        return result.get()
```

destroys all the parallelism. `result.get()` **blocks** until the worker process completes its task.  Only one worker can be active at a time then.  Don't you notice that only one of your cores is active?

Comment: I guess I haven't really noticed. I also know that its not calling the second for loop in do work. Can you suggest a different method about doing this? Btw, thank you for helping me, this an excellent learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by noting that `spc` is badly named at best - if it were described, we wouldn't need to reverse engineer its purpose. It is passed unaltered from main via parallel_bruteforce into do_work, where it is used in one line only:

```
suffix_len = int(math.ceil(math.log(spc) / math.log(n)) - 1)
```

This line suggests that it has to do with a length, but in a fairly convoluted mathematical manner. `n` is the character set size. The use of logarithms is appropriate for calculating the length of a string needed with a particular set of digits to represent a number of different values. For instance, `log(50000)/log(16)` is about 3.9 - telling us that we need 4 hexadecimal digits to count 50000 values, which matches well with 0xffff==65535. Dividing logarithms like this converts between logarithm bases; commonly only natural and base 10 logarithms are implemented (log and log10 in python), but `logx(n)=log(n)/log(x)`, [regardless of the base of log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base).

With that, we can see that `spc` most likely has to do with the search space - the number of attempts tried. The way it's used here must mean that this algorithm makes a specified number of attempts, rather than as many attempts as are needed for a particular width. If you have to raise the width, you need to raise spc to match: `spc=len(charset)**width`. This naturally reveals the exponential nature of brute forcing with a wider character set; it's going to be slow.

Comment: spc is shortnamed for strings per chunk. I apologize about naming conventions, I only used it for speed coding purposes. If you refer to the link at the bottom, it will show you it's original algorithm. The code I posted is just a cleaner version. Thank you for reverse engineering this algorithm. So, if I understand your answer, then strings per chunk is telling the workers how much space to search?

Comment: `strings_per_chunk` in the original code was an upper bound on the number of strings a worker process would examine per invocation.  That should be obvious ;-)  `for string in itertools.product(charset, repeat=length):` loops exactly `len(charset)**length` times.

Comment: BTW, if you have ;-) to use trickier code to do what was obvious with a tiny, fast loop, you can compute the base-x log of y via `math.log(y, x)` in Python.  No need to call `log()` twice and divide.