# Parallel Brute Force Algorithm GPU

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, brute-force

I have implemented a parallel BF Generator in Python like in this Post!
[Parallelize brute force generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132223/parallelize-brute-force-generation).

I want to implement this parallel technique on a GPU. Should be like a parallel BF Generator on a GPU.

Can someone help me out with some code examples for a parallel BF Generator on a GPU?

Couldn't find any examples online which made me suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this implementation - i did the distribution on the GPU with this code:

```
void IncBruteGPU( unsigned char* theBrute, unsigned int charSetLen, unsigned int bruteLength, unsigned int incNr){
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(incrementBy > 0 && i < bruteLength){
        int add = incrementBy + ourBrute[i];
        ourBrute[i] = add % charSetLen;
        incrementBy = add / charSetLen;
        i++;
    }
}
```

call it like this:

```
// the Thread index number    
int idx = get_global_id(0);

// the length of your charset "abcdefghi......"
unsigned int charSetLen = 26;

// the length of the word you want to brute
unsigned int bruteLength = 6; 

// theBrute keeps the single start numbers of the alphabeth
unsigned char theBrute[MAX_BRUTE_LENGTH];

IncrementBruteGPU(theBrute, charSetLen, bruteLength, idx);
```

Good Luck!